# table view tr class row numbering

Tags: 7, views, theming

I would like to have row numbers in my tr classes when displaying my view as a table. My rows seem to have only classes saying they're even and uneven.

Only possible in a tpl file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you just override views-view-table.tpl.php by copying/pasting this to your template folder in your theme, then use $row_count for your classes.

```
<tr <?php if ($row_classes[$row_count]) { print 'class="' . implode(' ', $row_classes[$row_count]) .' row-' . $row_count . '"';  } ?>>
```

Comment: exactly what I did :)

Comment: Notice that this code gives ".views-row-0" for the first row so if you need to start from 1 you have to add 1 to the $row_count variable.